# Convert array to Hashmap (key value pair) javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, hashmap

I have an array named territory which contains the following

[image]

i want to create a hashmap where
the

**key is the id  [id atribute of each object wihin territory]**

and the

**value is the entire object**

any help/pointers on the same?

thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi you could do like that and it will work :

```
var hashmap = {};

territory.forEach(function(element) {

    if(hashmap[element.id]!==null && hashmap[element.id]!=undefined){
       if(!Array.isArray(hashmap[element.id])){ 
           var tempObj = hashmap[element.id];

           // don't forget to json.stringify your object if you 
           // want to  serialise your hashmap for external use

           hashmap[element.id] = [tempObj];
       }

       hashmap[element.id].push(element);

    }
    else{
        // if you want to serialise your hashmap for external use
        hashmap[element.id] = JSON.stringify(element);
        // if not, you could just do without JSON.stringify
        hashmap[element.id] = element;
    }

});

console.log(hashmap);
```

you could look at mozilla documentation for more informations on foreach

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Edit : I updated the code to avoid (dirty) id duplication and store object who share the same id

Comment: thankyou for the quick reply ,but how do i handle duplicate id's , if i occur duplicate id's i want to do a summation and enter only one entry for that id

Comment: if you get the same id twice, with this code, it's gonna go to the key x and override inside previous data... that's it

Answer (score 5):

You simply need to iterate over the array and assign each element as a property in an object:

```
var hash = {};
var data = [...];
data.forEach(function (it) { hash[it.id] = it; });
```

If you have access to the lodash library, you can use [`indexBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#indexBy) to transform the whole array at once:

```
var data = [...];
var hash = _.indexBy(data, 'id');
```

The underscore library also has an [`indexBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#indexBy) method that behaves in the same fashion.